# Matthews correlation coefficient metric wrong during training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training a CNN with Matthews correlation coefficient as an observable metric, for that I defined my metric as follows:

```
def mcc(y_true, y_pred):
   y_pred_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1))
   y_pred_neg = 1 - y_pred_pos

   y_pos = K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))
   y_neg = 1 - y_pos

   tp = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_pos)
   tn = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_neg)

   fp = K.sum(y_neg * y_pred_pos)
   fn = K.sum(y_pos * y_pred_neg)

   numerator = (tp * tn - fp * fn)
   denominator = K.sqrt((tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn))

   return numerator / (denominator + K.epsilon())
```

Which I checked several times for correctness and re-implemented for validation purposes. I am fairly sure it is correct.

I compiled and fit my model as follows:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[keras_auc, mcc, 'accuracy'])
model.fit(train, y_train, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, shuffle = True)
```

During training I get the following output:

```
Epoch 11/15
6969/6969 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1075 - keras_auc: 0.9199 - mcc: 0.3622 - acc: 0.9567 - val_loss: 0.1003 - val_keras_auc: 0.9218 - val_mcc: 0.1558 - val_acc: 0.9610
Epoch 12/15
6969/6969 [==============================] - 14s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1064 - keras_auc: 0.9237 - mcc: 0.3852 - acc: 0.9552 - val_loss: 0.1009 - val_keras_auc: 0.9254 - val_mcc: 0.1205 - val_acc: 0.9650
Epoch 13/15
6969/6969 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0977 - keras_auc: 0.9271 - mcc: 0.3988 - acc: 0.9610 - val_loss: 0.1177 - val_keras_auc: 0.9284 - val_mcc: 0.0785 - val_acc: 0.9616
Epoch 14/15
6969/6969 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1037 - keras_auc: 0.9295 - mcc: 0.3943 - acc: 0.9571 - val_loss: 0.0961 - val_keras_auc: 0.9307 - val_mcc: 0.0802 - val_acc: 0.9621
Epoch 15/15
6969/6969 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0901 - keras_auc: 0.9321 - mcc: 0.4340 - acc: 0.9637 - val_loss: 0.1066 - val_keras_auc: 0.9337 - val_mcc: 0.1643 - val_acc: 0.9552
```

Here I can see that my metric for training is around 0.43 (and much higher for CV!), however if I do a prediction and calculate my metric, The result is around 0.71. (Which is certainly true and accurate)

I am looking for a way to calculate my Matthews correlation coefficient accurately during training, any advice would be of great help.

Comment: Are you aware that Keras includes MCC as a metric?https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/metrics/#matthews_correlation

Comment: Unfortunately they removed it in the current version! Nevertheless, I took the metric from the old version github repo.

Comment: You are right, just noticed it...